# Create custom "Smart Folders" in Gmail

Tags: gmail

At work I am *forced* to use gmail and tho I'd love to use it with Mail.App I don't want to mix my personal account(s) with work, so I prefer to use the native web gmail. But despite Priority Inbox and such, I still have a hard time finding some emails, probably because of years of muscle memory using Mail.app and smart folders.

I rarely access email in Mail.app from a folder, it's almost always through some sort of smart folder, these are a few of the ones I have:

[image: Smart Folders]

The question is: how can I create something like this is Gmail, is it even possible?

For example, the yesterday one in Mail.app looks like this:

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Some of those are available as customized searches. `is:unread` and `has:attachment` for instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I have found a way to do this. Turns out that you need 1 Lab and a custom query. Although the result is not exactly the same.

First you need the Quick Links Google Lab by Dan P.

[image: Quick Links]

Once you have the lab enabled, you can go ahead and click on the *advanced search* button:

[image: adv search]

Which will allow you to create a custom query (albeit way more limited than Apple's Mail, at least you will have some control).

I select Inbox (not interested in archived stuff or deleted or anything like that), then select (for this example) 1 week from *Today*. And press the blue magnifying glass to perform the search.

[image: popup]

After you see the results, click the *Add Quick Link* from the lab, as seen in the following image:

[image: addlink]

This will create a *dynamic* shortcut that will always point to "the last week" instead of fixed dates.

By using other dates and/or combinations you can create the "sense" of Smart Folders to always have a one click filter for your Family emails, and such.